# Dynamic Data Display simple example gives couple of errors?

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic-data-display

```
<d3:Chart BottomTitle="Argument" LeftTitle="Function">
     <d3:LineGraph x:Name="linegraph" Description="Simple linegraph" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="3"/>
</d3:Chart>
```

This code is on the [Home Page](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) of the Dynamic Data Display. I downloaded .dll file and added the reference. Then I add those lines of code shown on the home page to my `MainWindow.xaml`

I get these errors;

- 'd3' is an undeclared prefix.
- Chart is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.
- The namespace prefix "d3" is not defined.

I have no other code to show. This is the whole code because I was at the beginning.

Should I do something with this `DynamicDataDisplay.XML` file too? I didn't use it so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try add this namespace to your `Window/UserControl`:

```
xmlns:d3="http://research.microsoft.com/DynamicDataDisplay/1.0"
```

Comment: Now I get this. "The name "Chart" does not exist in the namespace "

Answer (score 0):

in Wpf you have to use "ChartPlotter" instead of "Chart". Chart is only supported in Silverlight.